# Nginx only following `location /` rule

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I'm new to nginx and want to create two different rules: One that specifies index.html as the response and one that forwards the request to a flask server via uwsgi. If I only include a single location block with `location /` I get the correct response depending on what I put inside the block (either the index.html or the expected response from flask), but if I put in both rules the `location /` block always works as expected while the `location /test` block responds with a 404.

I would expect the following server block to return the same index.html file for both `/` and `/test` but only the first one works as expected. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        root /var/www/src;

        location / {
                index index.html;
        }

        location /test {
                index index.html;
        }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing to fix, your expectation of how the index directive works is just wrong. A request to the second block will attempt to serve the file /var/www/src/test/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Module ngx_http_index_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html)

> Defines files that will be used as an index. The file name can contain variables. Files are checked in the specified order. The last element of the list can be a file with an absolute path. Example:

The important part is: "Defines *files*", not paths. This means, there has to be a file named `index.html` in the directory `test`.

If you really want to serve `index.html` from the root directory, you may utilize an absolute path as the last (in your case only) file

```
location /test {
    index /index.html;
}
```